# Bendable flaps on sheet metal

Tags: design, cad, metals, cutting, metal-folding

I'm trying to cut some bendable flaps on aluminium sheets for hooking/clipping onto some fabric. The flaps I have in mind look like this:

[image]

Are these common features? Does anyone know the geometry of the cutout? I wish SolidWorks had them as standard features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will need to be sized appropriate to the load that will be applied, which means that they are not “standard”.

You need to make sure the part that bends is sufficiently strong and will have sufficient life when it is flexed often.